# PrimeNG push item in breadcrumb from other module

Tags: javascript, angular, breadcrumbs

I try to make a breadcrumb based on PrimeNG breadcrumb. At this moment I have two different modules. 
In root App I have this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {     
        this.items = [];       
        this.items.push({label:'Lists', url: '/lists'});      
    }
}
```

And in app.component.html:

```
<p-breadcrumb [model]="items"></p-breadcrumb>
```

Which is ok!

But I want to push data **from other module**, like this:

```
export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {
...
   ngOnInit() { 
        let listId = this._activatedRoute.params['listId'];

        this.items = [];
        this.items.push({label: `Lists ${listId}`, url: `/lists/${listId}`}); 
    }
...
}
```

This is not appear, ListItemComponent don't have access to .

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with a shared service:

```
@Injectable()
export class BreadcrumbService {
    items: Array = [];
}
```

Provide that service in your top-level `AppComponent` module.

Now you can use it in the `AppComponent`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService);

    ngOnInit() {     
        this._breadcrumbService.items.push({label:'Lists', url: '/lists'});      
    }
}
```

```html
<p-breadcrumb [model]="_breadcrumbService.items"></p-breadcrumb>
```

And also in the other one:

```
export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService);
...
    ngOnInit() { 
        let listId = this._activatedRoute.params['listId'];

        this._breadcrumbService.items.push({label: `Lists ${listId}`, url: `/lists/${listId}`}); 
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Looks very good. I will try this approach and come back with news in next hours. Thanks!

Comment: Is close what I need, I this moment is pushed all items I navigate. I must find a way to push just single item per view. Thanks for info!

Comment: How exactly do you mean that? Do you mean it should `pop` the item again when navigating away?

Comment: For example, if I go to "Lists" is push "Lists" and then I go to List ID is push Lists ID and the I go back to Lists is push again Lists so the results is: Lists > List ID > Lists and so on..

Comment: Yeah, you probably have to think of some logic when routing away, to remove (pop) the current component.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://brianflove.com/2016/10/23/angular2-breadcrumb-using-router/

Comment: I will try to add just unique values, based on a "flag" in every component which push data to breadcrumb. In this way I have more control. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: if this post and usage is still valid, I recommend using ngrx store.

Comment: Would love to see your ngrx store flavored answer!